# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n\log^2(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {1}{n\log^2(n+1)}$$

**Attempt:** We note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \dfrac {n}{ \log^2(n+1)} = \infty$

Hence, for a sufficiently large $n: \dfrac {n}{ \log^2(n+1)} > 1$

Dividing throughout by $\dfrac {1}{n^2} : \dfrac {1}{n \log^2(n+1)} > \dfrac {1}{n^2}$

But I guess, this doesn't give anything.

Could anyone please give me a direction.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: From $n=2$ on the $n$-th term is less than $\frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$. Now use the Integral Test.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log^2(n+1)}< \frac{1}{\log^2 2} + \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log^2 x} dx$$

Comment: Bravo evaluation!

Answer (score 4):

What about [Cauchy's Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) ?

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\log^2(2^n+1)}\le\frac1{\log^22^n}=\frac1{n^2\log^22}$$

and now comparison test. The series converges.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, the integral test works wonder here, but I feel like Cauchy's Condensation Criterion is also a very good way to approach this question.

Here is it's statement :

Let $a_n$ be a positive, decreasing sequence. Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$

converges if and only if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}
$$
converges.

In your case, we would thus have to study the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^n \log^2 (2^n + 1)} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 \log^2 2}
$$
and this last series converges. This criterion works quite well whenever the integral would be hard to compute. It makes series that diverge diverge faster and series that converge converge faster, hence making them easier to study.